# Problem manipulating child entity of a OneToMany relation with Cascade ALL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I have a performance problem using bi-directional relationship (OneToMany - ManyToOne).

I have an entity `Interaction` that can have many `ClassifiedGroup` (see classes bellow for more details) but I have a specific use case where I need to delete few ClassifiedGroups and add few others.

The problem is that when I use the `InteractionRepository.java` itself (a simple JpaRepository) to save all modifications of related `ClassifiedGroup`, the code will have to fetch all groups from the database linked with an Interaction. It will also fetch many other attributes of the `Interaction` that can also be expensive. I do not want to manipulate the `Interaction` entity to delete/create new `ClassifiedGroup` but I also want to have the cascade type to `ALL` because I create the first groups when the Interaction is created and if I delete the interaction itself, all groups should be deleted.

I tried to create a `JpaRepository` for the `ClassifiedGroup` entity and manipulate it directly but I'm getting errors trying to save it:

Code:

```java
      List<ClassifiedGroup> toAdd = generate(); // generate list to add
      toAdd.forEach(g -> g.setInteraction(interaction));

      this.classifiedGroupRepository.saveAll(toAdd);
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.UUID' to required type 'br.com.stilingue.smartcare.entities.Interaction' for property 'interaction'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.UUID' to required type 'br.com.stilingue.smartcare.entities.Interaction' for property 'interaction': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:609)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:246)
    at org.springframework.data.util.DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.setPropertyValue(DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation$IdentifierDerivingDirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.setPropertyValue(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:367)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.getId(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:175)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractEntityInformation.isNew(AbstractEntityInformation.java:46)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.isNew(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:246)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:596)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:631)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:599)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy197.saveAll(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.stilingue.smartcare.event.interaction.update.strategy.impl.InteractionStilingueArrayUpdateStrategy.updateInteraction(InteractionStilingueArrayUpdateStrategy.java:78)
    at br.com.stilingue.smartcare.event.interaction.update.strategy.impl.InteractionStilingueArrayUpdateStrategy$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b5a01170.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
    at br.com.stilingue.smartcare.event.interaction.update.strategy.impl.InteractionStilingueArrayUpdateStrategy$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6a4de66a.updateInteraction(<generated>)
    at br.com.stilingue.smartcare.event.interaction.update.strategy.impl.InteractionStilingueArrayUpdateStrategyIntegrationTest.testShouldAddNewGroups(InteractionStilingueArrayUpdateStrategyIntegrationTest.java:114)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.UUID' to required type 'br.com.stilingue.smartcare.entities.Interaction' for property 'interaction': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:262)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:590)
    ... 120 more
```

I've found a few other issues saying if I have the `CascadeType.PERSIST` in the parent entity I will not be able to manipulate the child entity directly because the parent entity will be the "owner" of the child entity.

But I have to ask: is there any way to avoid this performance bottleneck? My Interaction entity have a few other `OneToOne`, `ManyToMany`, `ManyToOne` and `OneToMany` relations and every time I use the `InteractionRepository#save` all relations are fetched from database. I really need to be able to create/delete `ClassifiedGroup` entities by my own.

My classes:

**Interaction**

```java
package br.com.stilingue.smartcare.entities;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.google.cloud.spanner.hibernate.types.SpannerJsonType;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;

@Data
@Entity
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Table(
    name = "interactions",
    uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"pid", "channel", "universe_id"})})
public class Interaction {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Type(type = "uuid-char")
  @Column(name = "interaction_id", nullable = false)
  private UUID interactionId;

  @Column(name = "pid", nullable = false)
  private String pid;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "channel", nullable = false)
  private Channel channel;

  @Column(name = "universe_id", nullable = false)
  private Long universeId;

  @Column(name = "post_date", nullable = false)
  private Timestamp postDate;

  @ToString.Exclude
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @OneToMany(
      mappedBy = "interaction",
      cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
      fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
      orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<ClassifiedGroup> groups;

  // many other relations/attributes not relevant for the issue, but they also are loaded when I use InteractionRepository#save method

  // method when the Interaction is created the first time
  public void setRelations() {
    if (this.groups != null) {
      this.groups.forEach(group -> group.setInteraction(this));
    }
  }
}
```

**ClassifiedGroup**

```java
package br.com.stilingue.smartcare.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Table(name = "classified_groups")
@IdClass(ClassifiedGroup.PrimaryKeys.class)
public class ClassifiedGroup {
  @Data
  public static class PrimaryKeys implements Serializable {
    private Interaction interaction;
    private String descriptor;
    private String value;
  }

  public ClassifiedGroup(String group, ClassificationType type, String descriptor) {
    this.value = group;
    this.type = type;
    this.descriptor = descriptor;
  }

  public ClassifiedGroup(String group, ClassificationType type) {
    this(group, type, "");
  }

  @Id
  @ToString.Exclude
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(
      name = "interaction_id",
      referencedColumnName = "interaction_id",
      insertable = false,
      updatable = false)
  private Interaction interaction;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
  private ClassificationType type;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "value", nullable = false)
  private String value;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "descriptor", nullable = false)
  private String descriptor = "";
}
```

**ClassifiedGroupRepository**

```java
package br.com.stilingue.smartcare.repositories;

import br.com.stilingue.smartcare.entities.ClassifiedGroup;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ClassifiedGroupRepository
    extends JpaRepository<ClassifiedGroup, ClassifiedGroup.PrimaryKeys> {}
```

**InteractionRepository**

```
package br.com.stilingue.smartcare.repositories;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface InteractionRepository extends JpaRepository<Interaction, UUID>{}
```

I'm currently using Hibernate `5.6.5.Final`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mappings are incorrect - you'll need to look into JPA tutorials on how to map derived ids, but the error tells you what is wrong, pointing you at your ClassifiedGroup.interaction mapping(s). The PK class must use the Interaction's ID (a UUID), not the Interaction instance itself.

```
  public static class PrimaryKeys implements Serializable {
    private UUID interaction;
    private String descriptor;
    private String value;
  }
```

As JPA needs to insert the value into the defined "interaction_id" fk, your mapping within ClassifiedGroup should be *writeable*, similar to:

```
  @Id
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(
      name = "interaction_id",
      referencedColumnName = "interaction_id")
  private Interaction interaction;
```

For your other questions - yes, there are many many ways to handle what you want, but it is a matter of how much work you want to put in. Making relationships lazy avoids them being unnecessarily fetched, but you then have to consider serialization through other mechanisms and changes to detached entities. I don't trust Spring/JPA providers to automatically know what I want done when it receives a null value in a relationship, as it could be that the data wasn't serialized, or it could be a change. So where performance is a concern, I write my own merge methods to handle taking in serialized data (from say a REST interface) and determining how it should be merged into a managed instance if it exists.

Also note that CascadeType.ALL might not be what you really want. All you stated you want is that changes to the Interaction.groups list are picked up and that referenced ClassifiedGroups are removed with the Interaction, and as a convince so you can persist an Interaction and its groups list in one call. That is just `cascade={PERSIST, REMOVE}`. ALL includes merge, refresh and detach which have performance overhead and might cause you grief if you don't really need them. Merge especially - when you pass in an Interaction with changes and ClassifiedGroups within its list of groups, any differences in those ClassifiedGroups from what is in the database will get merged. This can lead to consequences like stale data overwrites, and of course has a large overhead, as merge will cascade over ClassifiedGroup references as well. Don't use cascade options lightly.

Comment: Hello Chris. You're right I only need these 2. I already changed it!

About the mapping yes, I agree. The problem is because I tried few other mappings but without success.

For example changing the interaction type of the PrimaryKey in the ClassifiedGroup class to UUID gets me this error when Hibernate is executing DDL to create table (ddl-auto):

'The column types are different for column `interaction_id` of table `classified_groups` and column `interaction_id` of table `interactions` in foreign key'

Comment: I personally don't like UUID types and would just use a java string type to make things more portable and generally easier to handle. You'll have to look into how/why Hibernate isn't respecting and applying the org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "uuid-char") definition on the  Interaction pk over to the ClassifiedGroup "interaction_id" fk definition - or post the actual DDL that is generated as it might be a DB limitation.

Comment: Adding @Type(type = "uuid-char") to the PK was enough apparently